# Video stream on Node server not working properly on Firefox only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, video-streaming, streaming

My goal is to stream a video file into chunks rather than loading and playing the entire file at once. It works great on Google Chrome and I am able to see the chunk sizes as they are logged to the console. Now when I try this on firefox but I'm getting nothing logged to the console. The video will play, but I am unable to fast forward past the 10 minute or so mark. Just curious why it works flawlessly in Chrome and not firefox?

```
router.get("/video", ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var id = req.query.id;
  let path = "";
  
  for (let k in movieLinks) {
    if (k === id) {
      path = movieLinks[k]
    }
  }
  // const path = "public/movies/noes2.mp4";
  const stat = fs.statSync(path);
  const fileSize = stat.size;
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    const start = parseInt(parts[0],10);
    const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize-1;
    const chunkSize = (end - start) + 1;

    console.log('RANGE: ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' = ' + chunkSize);
    
    const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start,end} );
    const head = {
      'Content-Range' : `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Content-Ranges' : 'bytes',
      'Content-Length' : chunkSize,
      'Content-Type' : 'video/mp4'
    }
    res.writeHead(206, head);
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    const head = {
      'Content-Length' : fileSize,
      'Content-Type' : 'video/mp4'
    }
    res.writeHead(200,head);
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
  }
  // res.render('video', {layout: 'videoLayout'});
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I done this before splitting video files with tool call [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

You can use the script below to split your video in 30 second chunks read them from a s3 bucket or wherever they may live. This will make browser download easier.

ffmpeg script example:

`ffmpeg -i input -c copy -segment_time 30 -f segment input.mov`

I hope this helps